# Is std::to_string thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, language-lawyer

I am looking to convert integer types to string using [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), but I saw this paragraph:

> `std::to_string` relies on `std::locale` for formatting purposes, and
>   therefore concurrent calls to `std::to_string` from multiple threads may
>   result in partial serialization of calls.

But I couldn't find anything else on this topic, Google didn't come up wit anything, as did MSDN. I am using Visual Studio 2013 if it matters.

Is this thread safe? If so, how?

Comment: Nothing about that quotes says it is not thread safe.  It is just that multiple calls might not run concurrently. That is a performance issue, not a safety one.

Comment: @Nathan Begs the question is std::locale thread safe?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Parts of it are not.  For instance `setlocale` is not thread safe so `std::to_string` might use a mutex to make sure multiple calls don't race if it calls that.

Comment: @NathanOliver That seems pretty insanely hideous and non-performant if `std::to_string` involved locking a mutex.

Comment: As to class `std::locale` itself: it is immutable, so there is no possibility of read/write race

Comment: And cppreference mentions that _"Internally, a locale object is implemented as-if it is a reference-counted pointer [...]"_. I expect global locale change and retrieval to happen atomically.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the prompt answer. Answer so I can mark it?

Comment: And thanks everyone for the great info

Comment: IIRC, no standard library function is allowed to produce hidden data races unless explicitly mentioned, so to_string should be safe, and as NathanOliver stated, the comment you quoted is "only" about performance.

Comment: @NathanOliver: They will run concurrently but may not run in parallel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::to_string` behaves as if it calls `sprintf` ([[string.conversions]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.conversions#7)), and the behavior of `sprintf` depends on the global locale, which can be modified by `setlocale` (or by `std::locale::global`, which internally calls `setlocale`).

The wording in [[clocale.syn]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/clocale.syn#2) seems to imply that `std::to_string` is thread safe, because it does not allow `setlocale` to introduce a data race with `std::to_string` or `sprintf`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer